# problem with showing modalviewcontroller in landscape mode in iphone?

Tags: iphone

my application consist of a landscape view where i want to put a modalview but the problem is with modalview. it doesn't get load on presenting it.. code is:

--------------------code here----------------------

UIViewController *modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

modalViewController.view = modelView1;
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];

[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

---

plz kindly help me with this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with ur code is that u are initializing it with `alloc-init`, without any nib name. Now when call:

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];
```

The view will load itself by calling its loadview method, and u have definitely nothing in that. So if u do want to initialize in the same manner, just try to move the line of code:

```
modalViewController.view = modelView1;
```

after:

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];
```

like:

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];
modalViewController.view = modelView1;
```

I think this would work then.

Hope this helps.

thanks,

madhup

Comment: thanx for replying but it works in both the way got a diff. problem.